# How to convert date from field for comparison on WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm working on Oracle Forms application. I have a field called `DOB` which has a date format of `08-May-1890`. I would like to convert it to `18900508` on `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger for comparison.

I'm very new to this and have no idea where to start. Below is the code that I'm currently working with.

```
BEGIN
    --Convert date from 08-May-1890 to 1890508
    IF( TO_CHAR(:EMPLOYEE.DOB,'YYYY-MON-DD') < 20180927)THEN
        --Do Something in here
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If employee.dob is a string, convert it to date, then to string, and the comparison value must be a string:

```
BEGIN
    --Convert date from 08-May-1890 to 1890508
    IF( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:EMPLOYEE.DOB,'YYYYMONDD', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'),'YYYYMMDD') < '20180927' )THEN
        --Do Something in here
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

if employee.dob is already a date, and comparing to a string:

```
BEGIN
    --Convert date from 08-May-1890 to 1890508
    IF( TO_CHAR(:EMPLOYEE.DOB,'YYYYMMDD') < '20180927' )THEN
        --Do Something in here
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

But if employee.dob is a date column, then **don't** convert it to a string, compare it to a date instead

```
BEGIN
    --Convert date from 08-May-1890 to 1890508
    IF :EMPLOYEE.DOB < to_date('20180927','YYYYMMDD') )THEN
        --Do Something in here
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I'd put my bet on the 3rd example. `:DOB` probably is s DATE datatype field.

Comment: Yes, :DOB is a date field. Your solution works for me thanks.